# How to find the Vertical size of a window displaying a web page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an ASP.NET Site that has a single Master Page.  On one of my pages in this site I display a PDF file as the content of the page.

I need a way to know the size that I can make the PDF control so that I do not create a scroll bar for the webpage (the PDF control has it's own scroll bar).

I was able to solve this horizontally by setting the width of the control to 100%.  Sadly this does not work for the Vertical size.

Any help is appreciated.

Vaccano

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use JavaScript.

I would like a solution similar to the one found here:
http://www.codeverge.net/ng.asp-net-forum.master_pages_themes_and_navigation_controls/masterpages-stretch-content-to-fill-height-of-the-page

That solution does not seem to work for me (not sure why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to determine this server-side, so you'll need to use JavaScript. I'd recommend the [jQuery Dimensions plug in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions).

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use JavaScript. I would like a solution similar to the one found here: http://www.codeverge.net/ng.asp-net-forum.master_pages_themes_and_navigation_controls/masterpages-stretch-content-to-fill-height-of-the-page 
That solution does not seem to work for me (not sure why).

Comment: This is the real link:  http://forums.asp.net/t/964672.aspx  (The other was a copy I think)

Answer (score 0):

If you do use JavaScript, however, there is a workaround where you can put that value into a HiddenField (Which of course JavaScript would see as an Input), and click a Submit button, all behind the scenes.  If you use an UpdatePanel, you may be able to get away with a partial postback without user intervention.

For the button clickery, look into Document.Forms[0].btnMyButton.Click();.